# How to skip all the column names in MySQL when the table has auto increment primary key?

Tags: sql, mysql, insert, primary-key, auto-increment

A table is:

```
mysql> desc gifts;
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| giftID        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name          | varchar(80) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| filename      | varchar(80) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| effectiveTime | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

the following is ok:

```
mysql> insert into gifts
    -> values (10, "heart", "heart_shape.jpg", now());
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
```

but is there a way to not specify the "10"... and just let each one be 11, 12, 13... ?

I can do it using

```
mysql> insert into gifts (name, filename, effectiveTime)
    -> values ("coffee", "coffee123.jpg", now());
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

but the column names need to be all specified.  Is there a way that they don't have to be specified and the auto increment of primary key still works?  thanks.

Comment: While this is opinion, explicitly specifying column names is generally good practise, this ensures that if the table is changed in any way in the future (an extra column added for example), the expected values go in the expected columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
values (NULL, "heart", "heart_shape.jpg", now());
```